# Any tool to convert zephyr to velocity template?

Tags: java, velocity

We are moving certain templates from sailthru to velocity is there any tool/snippet to import/convert from sailthru zephyr template to velocity.

also I have query that is velocity good choice for template engine for emails templates, we are planning to reduce data transfer time across systems, our templates are appx ~20kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did something similar by

1. Writing a small sed script (for loops are easy to replace , if's canbe tougher tougher) to convert to velocity templates
2. then running [VM velocity validator](https://github.com/todvora/velocity-validator)
3. If the number of errors were less fix by hand else improve the script

Note: There are several internal sailthru function that you may need to convert on your own e.g
https://getstarted.sailthru.com/site/personalization-engine/meta-tags/

https://getstarted.sailthru.com/new-for-developers-overview/zephyr-functions-library/horizon_interest/